# Ui-router dependency resolution error on minification?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

using ui-router's routing scheme and have a state where there is a resolve,
a dependency is injected into the resolve (minification syntax used). locally this code functions as expected and the dependency is found.

in production all code is concatenated and minified with uglifierjs.

I noticed that with all js minified, the dependency injected into the resolve is not found.

any thoughts as to that for which I am not accounting?

`[...]
,resolve: ['Service', function(Service){
            return Service.init().then(function(){
              return Service.setUser()
            })
          }]
[...]`

Comment: So, you sure that 'Service' is included (with the correct name) BEFORE bootstrapping angular?

Comment: At the moment you are bootstrapping angular (either by callling .boostrap() or using ng-app) you need to be sure that all services are loaded correctly. Hard to say how you can check it but I would start by looking at your minified file. Disable minifcation, just do concatination and look at the order stuff is loaded.